# textAlign working differently after upgrade to RN 0.59.3

Tags: android, react-native, gravity, text-align

Using React Native, I'm having issues with `textAlign` as it became working strangely on android after upgrade to **RN 0.59.3**

I want the text to be aligned **Right** (whatever the content), but it gives **Right with English** text, and **Left with Arabic** text

I have this simple code (I expect both lines to be aligned to the **right**)

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>تجربة تجربة</Text>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Test Test</Text>
</View>
```

Style :

```
title: {
   textAlign: 'right',
   alignSelf: 'stretch',
   backgroundColor: '#EEE',
   margin: 10,
   color: '#000',
}
```

it's working correctly on IOS, but incorrect on Android (after upgrade to RN 0.59.3) as shown below :

[image]

I can identify the problem due to [this change in gravity in RN 0.59.3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/871290f)

So now how can I ensure text alignment to the right ?

---

**Update:** it looks like a bug introduced with **[RN 0.59.3](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0593)**

I did downgrade to **RN 0.59.2** and the bug was gone

---

**Update:** The bug was fixed in **[RN 0.59.8](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0598)**

Comment: Have you tried `textAlign: 'left'` on the Arabic one?

Comment: The Arabic text will go to the right on Android and Left on IOS @JoseVf .. and it's not a solution because I want it to stick to the right whatever the content was

Answer (score 1):

Expected to be the style impacted of `<View>` outside of `<Text />`.

this is worked code

```js
return(
 <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.title}>تجربة تجربة</Text>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Test Test</Text>
      </View>);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    textAlign: "right",
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "#EEE",
    margin: 10,
    color: "#000"
  }
});
```

Android: Samsung Galaxy s9 plus

[image: Galaxy s9 plus]

Comment: it's impacted of `<View>` but it was not written just for simplicity

Comment: I've just tried your code, but didn't change any thing in the issue :(

Comment: It works like a picture above. Or is there another `<View/>` outside of `<View/>`?

Comment: Thanks for your help .. this is a photo from my device for your code https://imgur.com/a/2Dblqss ..
it's galaxy s8 plus & android 9 & RN 0.59.5 ...
can I know the version of RN and android you have ?

Comment: my phone Galaxy s9 plus & RN 0.57 & android 9

Comment: sorry but the problem happens in **RN 0.59.3+** .. maybe i will downgrade to **RN 0.59.2** to solve this bug

Comment: There was a text-related change in the version of "0.59." https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d2153fc

Comment: `ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/text/ReactBaseTextShadowNode.java` Take a look here.

Comment: Thanks.. actually RN 0.59.2 doesn't have this bug .. so it's related to this change in RN 0.59.3 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/871290f

Comment: Submitting a bug report to `react-native` would be helpful for the next version.